# Viewing in backbone data from RESTful service

Tags: javascript, python, web-services, backbone.js, flask

I am trying to view the collection i import from the service, using backbone on the client side, and python/flask as the service. When i make the GET request, i get the following data back:

```
{"entries": [{"Title": "my title 1", "Description": "My desc 1", "Info": "Info 1", "ids": 1}, {"Title": "my title 2", "Description": "My desc 2", "Info": "Info 2", "ids": 2}]}
```

But those entries are not showing on my page, even though i use fetch. This is my ListView code:

```
var app = app || {};

app.ContactListView = Backbone.View.extend({
 el: '#contacts',

initialize: function () {

    this.collection = new app.ContactList();
this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
    this.render();
this.listenTo( this.collection, 'reset', this.render );
},


render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function( item ){
    this.renderContact( item );
}, this );
},

renderContact: function ( item ) {
    var contactView = new app.ContactView({
        model: item
    });
    this.$('#ContactTable').append( contactView.render().el );
}
});
```

What might be the cause?

Comment: Try overriding your collection's [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method to return the array of entries.

Comment: Your welcome, I posted this as answer for completeness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because your collection is expecting an array of models as it's response but your service is returning the array under entries. From the [documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse)

> parse is called by Backbone whenever a collection's models are
>   returned by the server, in fetch. The function is passed the raw
>   response object, and should return the **array of model attributes** to be
>   added to the collection.

To work around that you can simply override your [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-parse) method to return the array of models.

For example:

```
app.ContactList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
      //...
     parse: function (response) {
         return response.entries;
     } 
})
```